# Como trocar conteúdo de uma div usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar um script para substituir tudo que estiver dentro de uma div por algo predefinido, sou novo em javascript e estou tendo trabalho para achar uma solução para isso, procurei em vários lugares, mas não consegui nada.

Estou chamando o script usando `url.searchParams.get`

```js
if(url.searchParams.get("sub") == 1) {
    document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "<p>Outro texto</p>"
}
```

```html
<div id="rep">Texto</div>
```

Comment: Vc criou o objeto URL?

Comment: O que seria `url.searchParams.get`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `searchParams` é uma propriedade do objeto `URL`. Portanto, para usá-la é preciso antes criar o objeto com uma URL válida. Caso queira usar a URL atual da página no objeto, basta usar como parâmetro a propriedade `location.href`:

```
let url = new URL(location.href);
```

Com o objeto criado na variável `url`, você consegue acessar a propriedade `url.searchParams` usando `get()`:

```
let url = new URL(location.href);
if(url.searchParams.get("sub") == 1) {
    document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "<p>Outro texto</p>"
}
```

Caso a URL da página contenha um valor `sub=1`, o `if` será acessado e o HTML da `div` será substituído.